# copying one segment of vector into another vector

Tags: c++, vector

`std::vector V` contains elements `a1, a2 ,a3, a4, a5, a6` and I need to copy elements from `a2` to `a4` in a new `std::vector NV`.

How is it possible to copy  range of vector into a new vector?
i did this uin my code as per recommendations but still i am not able to figure out?The part involved is this one.

```
                       vector<int>::const_iterator first = v.begin() + i+1;
                       vector <int>::const_iterator last = v.begin() + i+k;
                       vector<int>:: nv(first, last);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the NV directly using this:

```
std::vector<T> NV(std::next(V.begin(),1),std::next(V.begin(),3));
```

**Example:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    auto print=[](const auto& container){
        for(const auto& item:container){
            std::cout << item << "\t";     
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    };
    std::vector<std::string> V{ "a1", "a2" ,"a3", "a4","a5","a6"};
    print(V);
    std::vector<std::string> NV(std::next(std::begin(V),1),std::next(std::begin(V),4));
    print(NV);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/5flo)

Comment: @Human HELFAWI  can u look athe above code where i am trying to copy from the index i+1 to index i+k of avector into new vector nv